# Getting Information from Stack Overflow API using Java

Tags: java, api, stackexchange-api

Is there a Java wrapper for the *current* version of Stack Overflow? I have been looking at [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper) and [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/236/stackoverflow-java-sdk-a-java-wrapper-for-the-stack-exchange-api), but they seem to be outdated for current API version. I keep getting `connection refused` when running their example code. I do have an API key.

```
StackExchangeApiQueryFactory queryFactory = StackExchangeApiQueryFactory.newInstance("MyApplicationKey");
    QuestionApiQuery query = queryFactory.newQuestionApiQuery();

List<Question> questions = query.withSort(Question.SortOrder.HOT).withPaging(new Paging(1, 20)).withTimePeriod(new TimePeriod(new Date(), new Date())).withFetchOptions(EnumSet.of(FilterOption.INCLUDE_BODY, FilterOption.INCLUDE_COMMENTS)).list();
```

Comment: Connection refused is happening at the network level, not the API level.  You need to debug that first (IP address/hostname, port, firewall, etc) using Wireshark.

Comment: I have my proxy set up, and it's working fine with other things. I am getting an `StackExchangeApiException`.

Answer (score 0):

This was an internal proxy mixup. Make sure your proxy is set properly. Also, if you are using an IDE, make sure that Automatic Proxy Configuration is chosen in its settings.